# OpenCV pixels to milimeters rate changes from short to long object

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, camera, pixel, calibration

I have Logitech Brio 4K camera. I did calibrate it, and image seems to have straight lines. In the current setup, I measure object length and width, by counting pixels and then dividing it by ~1.63435... Distance to the object is fixed.

Problems are, shorter objects and longer objects have different pixel/mm rate.

If I take 2000 mm object and use its rate, 690 mm appears as 700 mm object.

What is missing? Do I have to account for Field of view or something? Could my calibration be bad?

Here are calibrations (If it helps) I use brio1:
https://github.com/mjasnikovs/horus/tree/master/calibrations

OpenCV, Python 3

**EDIT:**
I did multiple calibrations, even downloaded Matlab's tools. Same results.

Comment: Where does 1.63435 come from? Your calibration images seem to have a different aspect ratio.

Comment: @RevJohn just pixels/object_lenght = 1.6445...